# Error when sending a test from CiviMail

Tags: civimail

This is a new installation of CiviCRM 5.14.0 on WordPress 5.2.1

I've created a test CiviMail using one of the default templates. When I attempt to send a test mail, I get a pop-up that says "Sorry an error has occurred and your information was not saved."

Not much information here. I had a similar problem with a Joomla site five years ago but can't find my solution

Comment: Is everything at civicrm/admin/setting/smtp?reset=1 filled out correct? Can you send a test email from there? what is your choice for "Select Mailer"? Who is your web host, email provider, etc?

Comment: Are you running any security plugins such as WordFence?

Comment: Yes. The test email when configuring the SMTP server is working. If I send email in plain text format or a very simple HTML email, it works. There are other problems, which will be reported later.

The problem seems to be with the default templates provided.

There are no security plug-ins